# Can you refresh a nested object with JS so the attributes that depend on parent attributes are reloaded as well?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested

I have a `Plan` model which `has_many` `Version`s. I'm nesting a `Version` form inside a `Plan` form.

*form*

```
<%= simple_form_for @plan do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :version do |v| %>
    <%= v.input :amount, hint: "#{pricing_model_hint_for_amount(@version)}" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I build the Version in the PlansController #new action:

*controller action*

```
  def new
    @plan = current_account.plans.build
    @version = @plan.versions.build
  end
```

Now for example, the `@version` hint for the `amount` input depends on an attribute of it's parent `Plan` called `:pricing_model`. The input's hint attribute consumes a helper that will will look at the `@version.plan.pricing_model` to fetch the right hint from a YAML file.

*helper*

```
  def pricing_model_hint_for_amount(version)
    t("simple_form.hints.version.pricing_model.#{version.plan.pricing_model}")
  end
```

**Problem:**

Because `@version` is instantiated when the form is loaded, the hint is not updated dynamically when I change the `@plan` `pricing_model` in the form.

Is there a way (with or without Javascript) to *reload* the nested `@plan` so the form hints are updated accordingly if something in it's parent changes? If not, is there a way to reload the hint field itself so when the helper is consumed again the same result is achieved?

I hope I explained myself, otherwise please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I think this cannot be done without JS code in any way. You can look on https://www.hotrails.dev/ or any MVVM frameworks of JS (react, angular, ember) there are computed properties, I think that is you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

What version of rails are you on?

If you are on rails 7 you should look into using either:

a stimulus controller to listen on the changes and update your tooltip. (more js)

[How to create a controller](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers), and the [action you can listen to](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/actions).

or:

a [turbo-frame](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails#decompose-with-turbo-frames) to reload parts of your form on demand. (more ruby)

Comment: Thanks. Ended up using a StimulusJS controller indeed.